Image https link not showing in my webview in Xamarin.form
I have an ASP.NET application on IIS which is on an HTTPS certificate.
In my Xamarin form code I have a view and I use the following code to display the view.
var htmlSource = new HtmlWebViewSource();
 string taille = "15px";

htmlSource.Html = @$"<html>
                <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1'/>
                <body style='text-align:justify;font-size:{taille}'>" + article.message + "</body>" +
            "</html>";

myWebView.Source = htmlSource;

Captured result
The HtmlWebViewSource contains HTML so inside there are image links in HTTPS mode since we installed the certificate and force the redirection from HTTP to HTTPS
Since we did that we can no longer display the image but the text yes except the image which does not appear and when we type the link in the browser it is displayed
Thank you for helping us
